# Part of match in match. How to find all?

Tags: regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm looking for all variables in document and spot undesirable feature. During:

```
$from = "(some txt)$aaa$bbb(another txt)";
preg_match_all("/[\$]([a-zA-Z_]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9_]*?)(\W)/", $from, $matches);
```

script return only $aaa as a match but not $bbb. I have no idea how to work it out. Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of the none word token at the end of your regex which makes your regex match `$aaa$` (the `\W` match the last $). For refuse of such behavior you can put the `\W` in a positive look ahead.Also you can put all the regex between `$` and `\W` in one group :

```
/\$([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)(?=\W)/
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/uV1cA2/1

Comment: oO I didn't know about capturing groups. I thought it is just for clarification of code. Thanks ;)